# Multiplying a vector by scalar and type casting (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, templates, vector, operator-overloading

I am implementing a vector in 3D space: {u, v ,w}. I want to overload operator * such that the following operation is possible: **ResultVector** = scalar * **Vector**. In this expression I supposed that the type contained in the **ResVector** is the most common between the type of scalar and the type that contained in the **Vector**. For example, I expect the following type conversions:

`int * vector<float> -> vector<float>`

`complex<float> * vector<float> -> vector<complex>`

and so on. But I see that my overload of operator * does not work properly. So, how should I define operator* to provide the type conversions mentioned above and others?

What I have now:

```
template <typename Scalar>
Vector3<Scalar> operator*(Scalar number, const Vector3<Scalar>& vec1)
{
    Vector3<Scalar> tmp(vec1);
    tmp *= number;
    return tmp;
}
```

That overloading works only if number is the Scalar and vec1 contains Scalar. Moreover, operator* cannot be used like that

```
Vector3<float> vec1(1, 2, 3);
Vector3<float> vec5(2 * vec1);
```

since the appropriate type casting does not exist or operator* that accept appropriate types is not defined. But if I define operator* in the folowing way

```
template <typename Scalar, typename Multiplier=Scalar>
Vector3<Scalar> operator*(Multiplier number, const Vector3<Scalar>& vec1)
{
    Vector3<Scalar> tmp(vec1);
    tmp *= number;
    return tmp;
}
```

then the use case mentioned above, is possible. Why? How it works?

Comment: Use `std::common_type_t<Scalar, Multiplier>` or `decltype(Scalar{} * Multiplier{})`.

Comment: And what is `Vector3`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why would you expect your solution to not work? BTW: There's no need for the default template parameter for `Multiplier`. That said, this still doesn't work correctly, since it doesn't give the correct return type. If one is `float` and the other an integer, you should return a vector that has the same type as multiplication of the according C++ types would give.